# how long should it take to install when writing over the harddrive?

Tags: system-installation

Trying to put 14.04 on an older Toshiba Satellite (L775). Told it to erase the harddrive. It's been giving me the spinny circle and no progress bars or anything for going on four hours now. I could imagine that it might take that long or longer, because I had a lot of stuff on that harddrive. But I have no idea, really. Couldn't seem to find this anywhere. Thanks.

Also if it's broken what the heck do I do.

Comment: Depends, really. Installation on chromebook took me like 4 hours, on two Toshiba laptops - took me about 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad sign.  Abort the installation and boot with the Ubuntu Live-DVD, choose <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>, go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
sudo smartctl --scan
```

and for each line of output do a:

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/XdY
```

where X and Y are the letters of the drives that came up with the `smartctl --scan` command.